# Proof that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

I am trying to prove that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Is the following correct? (I am able to write a proof for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, but I also want to write one for a particular $\epsilon>0$.

Set $\epsilon=0.7$. Consider an arbitrary $\delta>0$. Set $a=b+\frac{\delta}{2}$. Set $b=\frac{1}{\delta}-\frac{\delta}{4}$. Then $|a-b|=\frac{\delta}{2}< \delta $ and $|a^2-b^2|=|(a-b)(a+b)|=|(\frac{\delta}{2})(2b+\frac{\delta}{2})|=|(\frac{\delta}{2})(\frac{2}{\delta})|=1>0.7$.

Comment: Yup! Just to be clear, your proof exactly as written is fine, with no caveats needed (except that you should define $b$ before using it to define $a$); if you wish to disprove that something is true for all $\epsilon$, there is absolutely nothing wrong with proving that it fails for a specific $\epsilon$—in fact, arguably, that's the *only* way to do it, though a sophisticated proof can be written to obscure that—and no requirement that you make any clever choice of that specific $\epsilon$ as long as you can find a counterexample for one.

Comment: To prove $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, you only need to indicate that the definition does not hold for one specific epsilon. Why do you want to prove for all epsilon?

Comment: You're able to show $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ by supposing any $\epsilon > 0$? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Accelerator - it's just the contrapositive; since uniform continuity requires a condition to hold for all $\epsilon>0$, its negation is that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that the condition does not hold.

Comment: @LostinNowhere Contrapositive of what implication statement? I'm just referring to the "an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$" part. I know they negated the definition in their attempt and the work looks fine. But the OP also claims they wrote a proof for $x^2$ not having uniform continuity for every real number by supposing $\epsilon > 0$, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A neater solution is to take $a_n:=\sqrt n$ and $b_n:=\sqrt {n+1}$. Then $|a_n-b_n|\rightarrow 0$ while for every $n$ we have $|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, you need to show that *there exists* an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there exists $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|x^2-y^2|\ge\varepsilon$. So it suffices to set $\varepsilon=0.7$, and prove that, for every $\delta>0$, there exists $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|x^2-y^2|\ge0.7$. You don't need to prove that *for every* $\varepsilon,\delta>0$ there exists $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|x^2-y^2|\ge\varepsilon$. That is a strictly stronger assertion than $x^2$ not being uniformly continuous (although that stronger assertion happens to be true in this case).

Your argument is correct, though perhaps the following argument, with $\varepsilon=1$, is cleaner:

> Let $\delta>0$ and set $k=1/\delta$. Then, if $x=k+\delta/2$ and $y=k$, we have $|x-y|=\delta/2<\delta$, and $|x^2-y^2|=k\delta+\dfrac{\delta^2}{4}>k\delta=1$.

To prove the stronger assertion, we can modify the above argument by setting $k=\varepsilon/\delta$.